# How create non SPA pages in angular6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I make simple SPA pages with routing. For old style routing i use follow ability:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
```

It worked OK.

One of these pages(/login) is NON SPA. 
routing:

```
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'login', component: LoginViewComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeViewComponent },
      { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogViewComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
    ], { useHash: true })
  ],
```

template:

```
<a href="/login">Login</a> |

<a routerLinkActive="active" 
   routerLink="/home">Home</a> | 

<a routerLinkActive="active" 
  routerLink="/catalog">Catalog</a> 

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I need make 2 NON SPA pages: /login, /home. Please help my.

[LIVE DEMO is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-15sgpm)

Comment: you can use angular universal or just express to serve those pages from server but it does not make why you would want to do that.

Comment: @fastAsTortoise but /login page worked without server magic

Comment: Its not login page its index.html that gets served from server. it then redirects to login as you have set that as your default route.

Answer (score 0):

routerLink compiles to a regular href. The angular router then intercepts them for angular's internal routing logic.

I assume your goal to to load a new page? Then you can use a plain anchor

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>
```

EDIT

remove the useHash at the end and use are normal href="/home"

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'login', component: LoginViewComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeViewComponent },
  { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogViewComponent },
  // { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  // { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
])
```

Comment: No, my goal to load /home

Comment: the new load trigger can always be done with a default href in anchor. Removing the useHash option in routing will work.